# Running GRASS r.watershed in Python returns SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment

Tags: python, grass-gis, r.watershed

I am trying to run `r.watershed` in my Python script using `GRASS`. I am trying to put in the appropriate parameters but I keep getting the error: `SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?`
Here's the code. What am I doing wrong here?

```
import grass.script as gscript

def main():
    gscript.run_command('g.region', flags='p')
    gscript.run_command('r.watershed', elevation = 
'C:/Projects/TWI/Data/Rivanna/USGS_10M_RCC_mos.tif', depression = 
'C:/Projects/TWI/Data/Rivanna/USGS_10M_RCC_mos.tif', flow = None, disturbed_land = None, blocking = None, threshold = None, max_slope_length = None, convergence = 5, memory = 300, -s = True, -m = False, -a = False, -b = False, tci = 'C:/Projects/TWI/Tests/QGIS_Grass/Script/10M/twi_10M_r_watershed_test2.tiff', GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER = None, GRASS_REGION_CELLSIZE_PARAMETER = 0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GRASS GIS all maps are stored in a specially formatted database. When you want to use these map layers you refer to them by the GRASS name. You cannot refer to an external Geotiff file within a GRASS module; you need to import it first. In fact, the only GRASS commands that accept a file path to some external file are the import modules `r.import`, `v.import`, and the equivalent export modules `r.out.gdal` and `v.out.ogr`.

Also note that the `threshold` parameter is crucial (and required) for watershed analysis. You cannot leave it `None`.

In your case I would suggest something like:

```
import grass.script as gscript
import os
data_dir = "'C:/Projects/TWI/Data/Rivanna"
elevation_tif = os.path.join(data_dir, "USGS_10M_RCC_mos.tif")

def main():
    
    gscript.run_command('r.import',
                        input=elevation_tif,
                        output="elevation")
    gscript.run_command('g.region', raster="elevation", flags='ap')
    gscript.run_command('r.watershed',
                        elevation = "elevation",
                        threshold = 1000,
                        direction = "flowdir",
                        accumulation = "flowacc",
                        basin = "basins", stream = "streams",
                        tci = 'tci', )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Again, you need to choose the threshold value carefully.
This should create 5 new GRASS raster maps: basins, streams, flow direction, flow accumulation, and topographic wetness.

If you need to export to a Geotiff, then add a call to `r.out.gdal`.

Comment: I had to modify what you posted, but I got it working to an extent. I just did not understand that the actual files had to be exported into the grass database folder. I am still having issues trying to display the output in the GRASS GUI and, more importantly, outputing the tci to an actual .tif file using r.out.gdal. I'll make another post for that. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You would probably benefit from one of the introductory websites, such as:  [Brendon Harmons blog](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Introduction_to_GRASS_GIS_with_terrain_analysis_examples) or the [GRASS intro to terrain analysis Wiki page](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Introduction_to_GRASS_GIS_with_terrain_analysis_examples)